# Office Add-in - SetAppRuntimeState error when open taskpane within shared runtime add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have an office addin project that uses shared runtime. I recently found this error when I try to open the task pane with `Office.addin.showAsTaskpane()` from function execution.[image]

The weird thing is that if I remove all custom functions of this add-in from the workbook, I will be able to open task pane again; also, I try copying all sheets from the workbook that has this issue to a new workbook, and everything works fine, I can open task pane on a new workbook.

So, I'm not sure if this error is related to a workbook-specific settings, or are there any APIs that I have to use to set AppRuntimeState.
Has anyone found this error before? This seems like an error from officejs api, but I'm not sure what the root cause is because I can't find any apis about SetAppRuntimeState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to call `showAsTaskpane()` without using shared runtime.  The workbook with the issue may be referencing an older version of your add-in manifest.

Please double check that shared runtime is correctly enabled and that you are calling it from a method that is part of the shared runtime. One easy way to verify is to try accessing a variable that is set in your task pane's context.

Comment: I clear everything in local storage, session storage, and cookie. Are there any other places that I have to clear to clear the reference to an old version?

Comment: I've tried clearing cache and cookie as well. It's still show the same error.
I think shared runtime is enabled because custom functions can access variable in window object that is set from command button.

Comment: You can try using the [Document Inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/using-the-document-inspector) (on Windows) to clear out any add-in related information that may still be embedded in the file.

Comment: Thank you! My add-in is working ok right now on the fixed workbook.